# Changing a MP3 files ID3 tags

Tags: php, mp3

I found a website recently that allows you to upload a file and change its ID3 tags (**Image**, **Title**, *all that other stuff*) and currently I am storing files in a directory after I parse them from another website before pushing them externally.

I am wondering if someone knows a library where I can read how to change the default ID3 tags in **PHP**? Is this a already existing feature with **PHP**?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.id3-set-tag.php - It took like 5 seconds to find this with Google. Next time put a little bit of research into your question.

Comment: @icecub what...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if( writeTags($row['title'],$new) ) { 
    $fileName = rand(000000000,999999999).'_'.rand(0000000000,9999999999).'_'.rand(000000000,999999999).'.mp3';
    $imageName = rand(000000000,999999999).'_'.rand(0000000000,9999999999).'_'.rand(000000000,999999999).'.jpg';
    rename($new, $DPATH.'uploads/tracks/'.$fileName);
    save_image($row['image'],$DPATH.'uploads/media/'.$imageName);
    $track['uid'] = 151;
    $track['title'] = $row['title'];
    $track['description'] = '';
    # fileName
    $track['name'] = $fileName;
    # make tag
    $track['tag'] = $tag.',';
    # download image
    $track['art'] = $imageName;
    # today date
    $track['release'] = date("Y-m-d");
    $track['size'] = filesize($DPATH.'uploads/tracks/'.$fileName);

    $row['slippery_id'] = add_to_slippery($track);
}

    function writeTags($title,$file) { 
    $TextEncoding = 'UTF-8';
    require_once($DPATH.'cron/getid3/getid3.php');
    $getID3 = new getID3;
    $getID3->setOption(array('encoding'=>$TextEncoding));
    require_once($DPATH.'cron/getid3/write.php');
    $tagwriter = new getid3_writetags;
    $tagwriter->filename = $file;
    $tagwriter->tagformats = array('id3v1','id3v2.3');
    $tagwriter->overwrite_tags = true;
    $tagwriter->tag_encoding = $TextEncoding;
    $tagwriter->remove_other_tags = true;
    $TagData = array(
       'album'         => array($MP3TAG),
       'comment'       => array($MP3TAG),
    );
    $fd = fopen($DPATH.'cron/mp3image.png', 'rb');
    $APICdata = fread($fd, filesize($DPATH.'cron/mp3image.png')); 
    fclose($fd); 
    $TagData['attached_picture'][0]['data']          = $APICdata;
    $TagData['attached_picture'][0]['picturetypeid'] = 2; 
    $TagData['attached_picture'][0]['description']   = $MP3TAG; 
    $TagData['attached_picture'][0]['mime']          = 'image/jpeg'; 
    $tagwriter->tag_data = $TagData;

    if ($tagwriter->WriteTags()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I recently did something similar, you can edit the above code to match your requirements, if you wanted me to be more helpful you should have provided your own code within your question.

Please note that asking questions like this is often how your questions get shut down, good luck in the future and I hope this helps you.

EDIT: Use this [GitHub](https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3) for getting the ID3 tags.

Comment: Not helpful for me

Comment: I'll remove my comment and just leave it as it is. But in my opinion, that's a whole lot of code for something that can be done with PHP's native [id3_set_tag()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.id3-set-tag.php) function, which takes like 10 lines of code.

Comment: @icecub as far as I'm aware, you can not set the image using the standard id3_set_tag() but I may be wrong, this is why I decided originally to use an external service in the first place.

Comment: I have to agree with you there. It seems it's possible with native PHP, but it's a huge hassle. A library is indeed a bit easier. +1 from me since I obviously missed the image part

Comment: VOTED UP for @Placeholder. -> "Bad" You can do a lot with getid3, like editing all fields, removing, updating, etc. Some more few codes in php can make a automation tag editor..

Answer (score 0):

I have recently made a PHP wrapper for eyeD3, a great python module for reading and updating ID3 metadata. Check it out [here](https://github.com/Stormiix/php-eyed3).
Usage is pretty simple if you're familiar with Composer. However, you will need to [install eyed3](http://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) in order to use it. Then:

1. Install the php wrapper using composer:

   ```
   composer require stormiix/php-eyed3 dev-master
   ```
2. Add the library to your code:

   ```
   require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
   ```
3. Use the following code to read & update tags.

   ```
   use Stormiix\EyeD3\EyeD3;

   $eyed3 = new EyeD3("mp3 file path");
   $tags = $eyed3->readMeta();
   // $tags is an array that contains the following keys:
   // artist, title, album, comment(s), lyrics ..etc

   $meta = [
       "artist" => "MyArtist",
       "title" => "MyTitle",
       "album" => "MyAlbum",
       "comment" => "MyComment",
       "lyrics" => "MyLyrics",
       "album_art" => "cover.png"
   ];
   // Update the mp3 file with the new meta tags
   $eyed3->updateMeta($meta);
   ```