# How to download an audio file with its all details using php

Tags: php, html

I want to download an audio file from my site with its Metadata that metadata is stored in the database so how I can download the file dynamically.

```
 <?php
  $path=$_GET['file'];
  list($file, $name) = explode('..',$path);
  header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
  header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
  header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$name.".mp3"); 
  header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
  readfile ($file);
 ?>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Or are you asking how to ADD those using php before it issues the download? (dynamically)

Comment: No, but all details are stored in the database. How I can add that details in metadata, Yes Dynamically

Comment: Ah. You might want to restructure your question to include that important tidbit :)

Comment: There is no call to database at all, what have you tried?? You should be fine querying for some identifier that is referrencing the file e.g the path

Comment: I will get the path and file name from the URL as you can see now question is that where I can add album name, artist name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing a MP3 files ID3 tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694964/changing-a-mp3-files-id3-tags)